# How to add a location to "Places" instead of "Bookmarks" in Nautilus/Ubuntu's File Manager?

Tags: nautilus, files, bookmarks

I want to add a custom bookmark to Nautilus's/Ubuntu's File Manager's sidebar, right under:

**Places**

As opposed to adding it right under

**Bookmarks**

[image]

Comment: Exact duplicate: [How can I edit Nautilus Places sidebar and Unity QuickList?](http://askubuntu.com/q/325518/52726)

Comment: @AlaaAli Yes, exactly, but the question can't be closed now.

Comment: @AlaaAli You failed to realize that this question is older than that question you just linked. Ergo; That question you linked is the duplicate; not this one.

Comment: @Akiva No, this website is not a game of which question is older than which; a question is marked a duplicate of another when the other has an answer that answers the question. The point of marking duplicates is to not have many questions asking the same thing, but rather a centralized one question that has the best answers. The other question I linked has a perfect answer. Ergo this question should be marked as a duplicate. You failed to do your search before awarding a bounty.

Comment: @AlaaAli I think you are correct. I apologize for not realizing this question was a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

You can't simply add a new location to **Places** like you add to **Bookmarks**. This because those locations are hardcoded into Nautilus. You can change the name or location of the directories or you can hide the directories by pointing them to **Home** by editing `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file, but you can't add new locations.

So, to add a new location to **Places** you have to edit the Nautilus source code. You can do this even if you are not a programmer by following carefully all the steps from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/351533/147044) (many thanks to [Roman Raguet](https://askubuntu.com/users/108850/roman-raguet) for it).

Comment: Hardcoded how? Binary or a config file?

Comment: @Akiva Can you open the link to the answer from my answer? If yes and if you will read it, you will understand :) Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the link. If I may however make a suggestion; I think you can still answer my question as a brief qualifier. For example "There is a solution, however it will require you to branch nautilus and rebuild it from source: Here is the link how to do it".