# How can I edit Nautilus Places sidebar and Unity QuickList?

Tags: nautilus

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 with Nautilus 3.6 and I want to edit the **Nautilus Places sidebar** menu **(Not Bookmarks)**.

By default have the following items: *Recent, Home, Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures, Videos & Trash.*

I wish:

> - **Add folder to Places (Not Bookmarks).**
> - **Added Folder must be present in Unity QuickList (Right Click Nautilus icon in Launcher).**
> - **Remove Recent files (Default in Nautilus 3.6).**
> - **Rename Trash to another name.**

how can I achieve these goals?

**NOTE:** *I tried editing `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file, but not luck. Is there another way to customize Nautilus Places menu?*

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In order to achieve that.. you should edit the Nautilus source code and the `nautilus.desktop` file or using another file manager that allows this, such as nemo.

---

### NOTE: In this example I'm running ubuntu 13.04 with nautilus (files) 3.6.3.
 You can test this in a virtual machine to see if everything is OK.

---

**1)** Make sure you have enable the [Source code repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221899/how-to-download-source-code-with-apt-get)

- Open the Ubuntu Software Center
- In the Menu Bar choose **Edit -> Software Sources**. Click to enable **"Source code repository".**
  Just in case I use the **"Main Server"** to Download.

[image]

Open a Terminal Window to update the repositories.

- `sudo apt-get update`

**2)** In the Terminal type the following to install the necessary packages.

- `sudo apt-get install build-essential quilt`

**3)** Install build dependencies.

- `sudo apt-get build-dep nautilus`

**4)** Create a folder to download the source code.

- `mkdir ~/Downloads/src`
- `cd ~/Downloads/src`

**5)** Download the source code & Export variables.

- `apt-get source nautilus`
- `export QUILT_PATCHES=debian/patches`
- `export EDITOR=gedit`

**6)** Create the patch and edit the source code.

- `cd nautilus-3.6.3/`
- `quilt new my_custom_places.patch`
- `quilt edit src/nautilus-places-sidebar.c`

---

**Custom Trash:** To change the name of the Trash.You can change the strings in the lines **567** and **569**.

eg: *"Trash" to "Custom Trash" & "Open the trash" to "Open the Custom Trash"*

[image]

---

**Add Folder:** In this example I will add the **"Test"** folder in my home directory **/home/virtual/Test**. *(change the folder according to your needs)*

After the line number **562** add the following:

```
/* add Test directory */
mount_uri = "file:///home/virtual/Test";
icon = g_themed_icon_new (NAUTILUS_ICON_FOLDER);
add_place (sidebar, PLACES_BUILT_IN,
       SECTION_COMPUTER,
       _("Test"), icon, mount_uri,
       NULL, NULL, NULL, 0,
       _("Open Test folder"));
g_object_unref (icon);
```

[image]

---

**Remove Recent Files:** To remove the Recent Files from the places... delete the lines from **525** to **534**.

[image]

Save the changes.

---

**7)** Build the deb packages.

- `quilt refresh`
- `fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage`

**8)** Install the deb packages.

- `cd ..`
- `sudo dpkg -i *deb`

**9)** For system-wide..edit the **nautilus.desktop** file to add the folder eg:*(/home/virtual/Test)* in the quick list.

- `sudo nano /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop`

**Change:**

```
Actions=Window;
```

**To:**

```
Actions=Test;Window;
```

**Add:**

```
[Desktop Action Test]
Name=Test             
Exec=nautilus --new-window /home/virtual/Test
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

**10)** Finally you can logout and Login to see the changes.

**RESULT:**

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: My version of nautilus is nautilus-3.10.1. In step #6 after I `cd nautilus-3.10.1` and then run `ls src` from there I find that nautilus-places-sidebar.c is not found in the source.  Where do I make the changes listed in step #6 above for nautilus 3.10.1 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS? My goal here is to just add a directory to the places sidebar.

Comment: would be cool, to see how this works with nautilus 3.10

Comment: Just curious whether this is something related to security or not...this is avery elaborate procedure for a relatively straightforward (requirement-wise not implementation) customization feature.

Comment: @Roman Raguet Kindly update the same for Ubuntu 14.04 http://askubuntu.com/questions/516999/create-folders-under-places-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: After 10 years, still no way to do it without touching the source code?

Answer (score 11):

I found an easy way outlined on SO.

Please follow the instructions outlined in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/a/292727/18487) - this solved the same problem I had.

Excerpts:

```
gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

Remove the list you do not want. However, once you login again, it will reset, so

```
echo "enabled=false" > ~/.config/user-dirs.conf
```

Comment: cool! a pity is doesnt have the trash folder so I could disable it :)

Comment: Thank you, this is a reasonable answer and works great in 14.04. This is not 1999; I'm done with recompiling my operating system just to make it work!

Comment: Also note that you'll need to kill and restart nautilus for these changes to take effect: `pkill nautilus` should do the trick.

Comment: I don't have a `~/.config/user-dirs.conf` and I'm running 14.04. Do I create it?

Answer (score 2):

For nautilus of ubuntu 14.04, you will have to edit gtk3.10, the same way as stated above, as the SideBar functionality was now ported into gtk (so that the file-open dialogue sidebar and the nautilus-sidebar are not separated implementations any more)

edit `/gtk/gtkplacessidebar.c`

I also tried this http://pastebin.com/K4GcHrz7 in `nautilus-window.c`, as there is https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkPlacesSidebar.html#gtk-places-sidebar-add-shortcut but get a segfault, not a good (gtk) programmer though.

Comment: pastebin link has been removed!

Answer (score 2):

On my system (Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS), the file you want is found at `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` Older versions used to keep this in `~/.gtk-bookmarks`.
Entries are URIs, so filepaths must be absolute and prefixed with `file://`.

Comment: This is incorrect at best. A *red flag* should have been thrown when you typed the file names: they share a word with what the OP explicitly stated, he does not want - **Not Bookmarks**. Please **read** the question and **answers** before polluting the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Just drag and drop the files to the bottom left when at a folder! (Nautilus 2.32.0)

I also posted the screenshots at gonorthwork/view for future archive reference:

[image]

[image]