# How can I place the nautilus - nemo sidebar to the right?

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, nemo

Is there a way to place the sidebar of nautilus and/or nemo to the right and not in the left?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/325518/how-can-i-edit-nautilus-places-sidebar-and-unity-quicklist not exactly what you asked for but might be worth a look

Comment: @Fabby can you please show me the duplicate question?

Comment: Someone pointed out to me that I should have read your question in more depth and that you want to move the side *pane* to the right instead of the left, which is going to take coding, not configuration.

Comment: I suppose a recompile of Nautilus with changes should fix it. It did when a user wanted to change the 'Computer' label on Nautilus.

Answer (score 1):

The position of the sidebar, as per my knowledge, is specified in the source code and any change in that position would require a recompilation after making the necessary modifications.

If you are fluent with C, get the source code using `apt-get source nautilus` and start modifying

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Unity sidebar then this might help:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/introducing-unity-tweak-tool

Comment: Link only answers are not very well appreciated. Please provide more details in your answer.