# Nautilus remove or edit "Places" in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, nautilus

I recently changed my System settings> Language Support to English. I want to delete Places in nautilus like Music, Videos, Documents. I was (probably) able to do so in my native language by changing following file:

/home/honza/.config/user-dirs.dirs

Now, this file is replaced by its original after editation and loging off. I found this help:

[How can I edit Nautilus Places sidebar and Unity QuickList?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325518/how-can-i-edit-nautilus-places-sidebar-and-unity-quicklist)

but it is too long and complicated for me. I was able to change direction e.g. Downloads by command:

xdg-user-dirs-update --set DOWNLOAD $HOME/somedirectory

but I want it not to be visible at all in nautilus. I also surmise that there is global settings in:

/etc/xdg/

but I do not know what to change. I do not know how xdg and nautilus are connected. I suppose xdg settings is more general than nautilus, which I am primarily interested.

Comment: Did you try this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/484977/75060 it is not so complicated.

Comment: yes @Mark ,before a while, actually it is a solution for me.